# Python nested loop

Tags: python, nested

Hello I am new to python and have a question about the best/pythonic way to do nested loops.

I want to go put each directory in an array with a nested array of the file contained in a that directory.

I have been looking at pythons arrays, dicts, sets and tupples and not sure of the best way to do this

[ Note I just want to do this for one level not recursively through all directories  ]

Currently I have a function that adds all the files of sub-directories to an array, but now I need to return their parent folder too.

Thanks in advance

```
    def getffdirs():

    filedirs = []

    path = os.curdir

    for d in os.listdir(path):      

        if os.path.isdir(d):
            print("Entering " + d)

            curPath = os.path.join(path, d)
            for f in os.listdir(curPath):      

                if os.path.isfile(f):
                    print("file " + f)  
                    filedirs.append(f)     
    return filedirs
```

Comment: If you're going to use this for anything other than learning I would suggest using os.walk

Comment: In general, I agree, but what if you only want a single level?

Comment: Hey @jeff As I said I was new to python, I looked  at os.walk but thought it might be overkill for one directory level. Would os.walk be better ?

Comment: @Keet: `os.walk` is the **only** correct solution.  One level or 100 levels.

Comment: @Keet no it's not overkill because `os.walk` will return a `generator object` (very cool/efficient python tool) For example `foo = os.walk()` to get the `generator object` and `levelOne = foo.next()` for the first level list. Two lines of code... not bad.

Comment: thanks for clearing that one up !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd use a dictionary for this purpose, the keys would be directories and the values lists of files:

```
def getffdirs():

  dirs = {}
  path = os.curdir
  for d in os.listdir(path):      

    if os.path.isdir(d):
        print("Entering " + d)
        dirs[d] = [] # add directory with empty list

        curPath = os.path.join(path, d)
        for f in os.listdir(curPath):      

            if os.path.isfile(f):
                print("file " + f)  
                dirs[d].append(f) # add files to appropriate directory
  return dirs
```

to access the data:

```
for dir,files in dirs.items(): # notice the call to dirs.items(), thats what was missing.
  print "directory: ",dir
  print "files:"
  for f in files:
    print f
```

Comment: Thank for that. That seems like what I am after but I get a 'ValueError: too many values to unpack' error. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you want a dictionary,

EDIT 2: If you want to omit hidden directories,

```
from os import listdir, curdir
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join

filedirs = dict((d, [f for f in listdir(d) if isfile(join(d,f))]) 
                for d in listdir(curdir) if isdir(d) and d[0] != '.')
```

---

Original:

Is this what you're looking for?

```
filedirs = [[f for f in os.listdir(d) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d,f))]
            for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, your original solution only returned the files as I had already, but both were interesting approaches ! I think you're right, dictionary's are the way to go.